# Populate variables in terraform.tfvars file on local VSTS Linux Agent from online VSTS Process or Group Variable

Tags: git, azure, ubuntu, azure-devops, terraform

I did set up an Infrastructure As Code (IAC) build pipeline with Azure, Terraform, Ansible, GIT and Visual Studio Team Service (VSTS). I have also set up a VSTS agent on my local machine that is synchronized with the VSTS online. The setup currently works seamlessly and anytime I change my Terraform infrastructure specification on my local Ubuntu machine, and commit the changes to my GIT repository, it automatically updates the VM definition in Azure.

[image: Terraform variables.tf]

**The Problem**

As shown above I have a some application variables like Azure Subscription ID, Username, Password e.t.c that I don't want to commit to my public repository. Therefore, I am defining them as group variables in VSTS and I need them to be downloaded / synchronized to my local Linux agent in the terraform.tfvars file.

Please how can I accomplish this.

Comment: I don't know Azure that well but does it not have the concept of something like AWS' IAM roles that can be assumed by services such as VSTS and allow those to be used instead of having to provide credentials yourself?

Answer (score 2):

We use a bunch of techniques to move sensitive data out of scripts. Some examples:

- Terraform back-end credential in environment variables (see https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/index.html#testing for a list)
- Password, Keys and Certificates pulled down from Key Vault using [key_vault_secret](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/d/key_vault_secret.html)
- Variables in `terraform.tfvars` files pulled from a different, locked down repository; this is trivial with Release Pipelines that accept multiple input artifactories. You can also generate this file on-the-fly with a little Powershell

Just make sure that the pipeline cleans all these secrets after itself: VSTS will not do this for you.